# Create a Python function that allows user to pass in file name exactly as typed

Tags: python, unicode-escapes

I've seen similar questions to this one but they were older posts so I thought I would ask here again. I'm writing a function where I want a user to be able to pass in a Windows filepath, and for the function to be able to accept the filepath exactly as typed so the user doesn't have to worry about escaping the backslashes, preceding the string with 'r', etc.

However, I'm not aware of a way to prevent the `unicodeescape` error or other such errors that can occur when regular strings are used as file paths instead of raw strings, because if a user types in a regular file path like `C:\Users\temp` for the function to take, then as soon as the function signature sees that regular string with the `\U` in it, the function will immediately throw the `unicodeescape` error without ever giving me a chance to fix the string entered by the user.

Below is some example code that fails because the `filepath` string passed to the function contains a `\U` character, and I don't ever have a chance of fixing the string before the error. Is there a way to write a Python function that accepts a Windows file path exactly as typed by the user? I've also tried using `Path` from `pathlib` with no luck.

```
>>> def enter_filepath(filepath):
...     print(filepath)
...
>>>
>>> enter_filepath("C:\Users\temp")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    enter_filepath("C:\Users\temp")
                                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>>
```

Comment: How about `enter_filepath(r"C:\Users\temp")`?

Comment: Escape sequences aren't processed in user input. The problem here isn't with what the user passes in, it's just with the way you entered the prompt in the program.

Comment: Use a raw string when you want literal backslashes in the string.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. In my question I mention that I don't have a chance to change the string entered to a raw string, and if the user is a non-Python user and just wants to enter a file path, how do I allow them to do that without the function throwing an error and exiting? That is my question. I am aware of how to code file paths with raw strings or \\ or that kind of thing. The question here is around user input when the user is not aware of those requirements and just passes in a simple file path to the function.

Comment: I think Barmar is correct. There is no processing of input strings. if you use filepath = input('prompt') then you can open the file or whatever using filepath even if the user enters single backslashes as part of the input.

Comment: Yes that's true but if the function `enter_filename` needed to be called in bulk, it would be nice to have no input() prompts so I would like to avoid them if possible :) I suppose I could catch the unicodeescape error and tell the user they need to enter their filepath argument with 'r' in the front lol

Comment: Maybe worth noting that Windows accepts forward slashes in Python path names.

Comment: Yes but the question here is around accepting a path name as the user types it. The user may not know that Python has a built-in "hack" so that it can accept forward slashes in file paths. Sounds like my best bet is to catch the error and let the user know they have to enter the file path with a preceding 'r' if they're passing the file path straight to the function as an argument.

Comment: Maybe you can use input('prompt').replace('\\','/'). Personally I find user input of filepaths is error prone and you have to catch the errors and so with Windows I use a simple Windows-like dir/file selection coded using tkinter filedialog - this has the benefit that users are very familiar with it.

Comment: I am a little unsure of what you are referring to when you say "a user types in a regular file path like `C:\Users\temp`". Where or how is the user typing it in? Is this at the `input()` method prompt? Being read from a file? Directly in a script?  The only way I can reproduce your error is entering it directly into a script. It gives an error because it is not valid Python syntax. If this is the case, why are you getting a non-Python user to enter values directly in a script?